# What's a good standard reply to questions looking for unlikely research?

Tags: discussion

JonW's answer to [this meta question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/are-questions-asking-for-research-on-topic) puts forward a good reason why questions looking for studies or research shouldn't actively be discouraged, but I figure there are so many times that the answer to questions like this begin "It's unlikely that research into what's the optimal place to put a survey link..." that it's might be worth collaborating on a stock reply.

Anyone have strong feelings about this?